# Responsive React Playgrond: share state with iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I want React components inside and outside an iframe to access the same state.

As an example i want a Panel to adjust the state outside the iframe that immediately rerenders the react component inside the iframe. Vice versa, I want changes to the component inside the iframe to propagate to the settings panel outside the iframe.

What are my options?

(The purpose is to build a way to preview how a component behaves responsively and iframe seems to be the most reliable option?)

Answer (score 1):

I think that simple application state managing like MOBX will be a good solution for you.

you should keep the share variables which you want to change as an observable, and the components will observe it, like this any change will trig a rerender.
also, the components will be able to change this variable as well it as well.

guideline for the process-
if I understand correctly your idea,
you want to change the width or height or any other property of a component from the panel and it will change the component size in your awesome playground?
so, in the mobx 'way' 
The hight and width will be saved in the 'store' as an observable
and the panel and the playground will observe it,
and also will be able to call an action to change in the store

[The Mobx library](https://mobx.js.org/index.html)

[the best tutorial](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html)

Comment: But how would the state in the store get shared from the iframe to the parent and vice versa?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use Iframe and not a simple div or even a component class that you can implement as you wish to react the panel changes.

now how your iframe render your inside component?

Iframe- `An inline frame is used to embed another document or web page within the current HTML document.`

this is not your case.

Comment: From here to give some more context: “There are several reasons you would want to render to an iFrame but the main benefit is style encapsulation. We can safely style our components without having to worry about style inheritence or CSS specificity and vice versa not affecting the parent document styles. The other benefits that are beyond the topic of this post are guaranteed paint layer and layout boundaries. Basically causing paints and reflows won’t effect the parent document as iFrames are essentially a new window.”  https://medium.com/@ryanseddon/rendering-to-iframes-in-react-d1cb92274f86

Comment: @dani So you want to build an app that is used on other websites? If you're just worried about CSS name collisions, then using BEM and prefixing your classnames with an app specific namespace should be enough, http://getbem.com/introduction/.

Answer (score -1):

don't use Iframe this will work for you.
'your component' should be an external component that its style depends on its props.

[simple play ground](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly0p64zwzm)

if you would like also to drive data from the component to the panel Mobx will be the best fit for you.